# Manipulating data obtained with indexedDB

Tags: javascript, async-await, indexeddb

Im new with IndexedDB and I can not manipulate the data obtained from indexedDB table.I only need do a search values when a button is pressed, then the event activated with the button starts to work and it has to return many results, which may take a few seconds to return values, so I need to use `async / await` in the callback function.  I think the problem is synchronous because I make the callback function `async` and the function `getData()` with which I get the data has the word `await` with it, even so, I can not work with the data, because when I do the `console.log(x)` it returns the `undefined` value.

```
let db;
let request = window.indexedDB.open("Cities", 1);

request.onerror = function (event) {
    console.log("error")
};

request.onsuccess = function (event) {
    db = event.target.result;
    document.getElementById('search').addEventListener('click', async function () {
       let x = await getData();
       console.log(x)
    })
};

function getData() {

    let transaction = db.transaction(["City"], "readwrite");

    transaction.oncomplete = function (event) {
        document.querySelector('body').innerHTML += '<li>Transaction completed.</li>';
    };

    transaction.onerror = function () {
        document.querySelector('body').innerHTML += '<li>Transaction not opened due to error: ' + transaction.error + '</li>';
    };

    let objectStore = transaction.objectStore("City");

    let objectStoreRequest = objectStore.getAll();

    objectStoreRequest.onsuccess = function () {
        document.querySelector('body').innerHTML += '<li>Request successful.</li>';
        let myRecord;
        return myRecord = objectStoreRequest.result;

    };
```

Of course, the `console.log(x)` is only to check that the data obtained is correct, once that point would come the part of the search but that is another story.
I'm not sure if my problem is with `async / await` or because I do not get the IndexedDB data correctly. Any help?

**EDIT:** -- I think I have found a solution, even though I think it is not the best way to solve the problem. I have moved all the code of the function `getData()` within the function that invokes the event, once the data is obtained I work within the method `.onsuccess` of `objectStoreRequest`, thus I avoid having to use `async / await`, I also continue working on the transaction which has not yet been finalized. If someone knows a cleaner way to make it work or explain to me why the original post code does not work, I would be very grateful.
I attach the code with which I am currently working:

```
let db;
let request = window.indexedDB.open("Cities", 1);

request.onerror = function (event) {
    console.log("error")
};
request.onsuccess = function (event) {

    db = event.target.result;
    document.getElementById('search').addEventListener('click',function () {

        let transaction = db.transaction(["City"], "readwrite");

        transaction.oncomplete = function () {
            document.querySelector('body').innerHTML += '<li>Transaction completed.</li>';
        };

        transaction.onerror = function (event) {
            document.querySelector('body').innerHTML += '<li>Transaction not opened due to error: ' + transaction.error + '</li>';
        };

        let objectStore = transaction.objectStore("City");

        let objectStoreRequest = objectStore.getAll();

        objectStoreRequest.onsuccess = function () {
            document.querySelector('body').innerHTML += '<li>Request successful.</li>';
            let myRecord;
            myRecord = objectStoreRequest.result;
            console.log(myRecord)
        }
    })
};
```

Anyway it seems like no one have another way for resolve this, so Im go to respond myself this post with this response.

Comment: You only need to consider using the `await` and `async` qualifiers when you work with JavaScript's `Promise` feature. Your code examples show you are not, so I would remove the discussion of this from your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the only way I have found to solve the problem, although it seems like a dirty code, I think it could be improved.

```
let db;
let request = window.indexedDB.open("Cities", 1);

request.onerror = function (event) {
    console.log("error")
};
request.onsuccess = function (event) {

    db = event.target.result;
    document.getElementById('search').addEventListener('click',function () {

        let transaction = db.transaction(["City"], "readwrite");

        transaction.oncomplete = function () {
            document.querySelector('body').innerHTML += '<li>Transaction completed.</li>';
        };

        transaction.onerror = function (event) {
            document.querySelector('body').innerHTML += '<li>Transaction not opened due to error: ' + transaction.error + '</li>';
        };

        let objectStore = transaction.objectStore("City");

        let objectStoreRequest = objectStore.getAll();

        objectStoreRequest.onsuccess = function () {
            document.querySelector('body').innerHTML += '<li>Request successful.</li>';
            let myRecord;
            myRecord = objectStoreRequest.result;
            console.log(myRecord)
        }
    })
};
```